# Subtracting DateTimePicker to textbox value the answer is in another textbox

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to solved and get the total running time in my program. Here's the sample below:

Thank you in advance!

Get the Datediff of two datetimepicker then subract the total of Datediff and textbox value.

```
Dim HoursDiff = DateDiff(DateInterval.Hour, DTPTS.Value, DTPTE.Value)

            Dim minutesDiff = DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, DTPTS.Value, DTPTE.Value)

            Dim totalMin As Integer = minutesDiff Mod 60

            Dim TotalTOT As String = HoursDiff & ":" & totalMin

            Dim totalcomTOT As Integer = TotalTOT - txtboxDownTime.text

            TxtboxTOTint.Text = totalcomTOT
```

Comment: Why not just use `Convert.ToInt32(minutesDiff) - Convert.ToInt32(txtboxDownTime.text)`? You cannot subtract 2 text values and cast it as integer directly, use integer conversion before outputting by `TxtboxTOTint.Text = totalcomTOT.ToString()`.

Comment: You can't subtract a `String` from a `String`.  Both `Strings` would have to be converted, either implicitly or explicitly, to numbers in order for subtraction to occur but at least one of your `Strings`, i.e. `TotalTOT`, doesn't represent a valid number.

Comment: Both `Value` properties are type `DateTime`.  Simply subtract one from the other to get a `TimeSpan` value.  That has `Hours`, `Minutes`, `TotalHours` and `TotalMinutes` properties that you can use.  If you have the downtime as a number of hours or number of minutes then you can subtract those as numbers.  Otherwise, create a `TimeSpan` from your downtime in whatever way is appropriate and then subtract that from your total to get a final `TimeSpan` value.

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful advice. I'm just a beginner in programming and I really want to learn more and this advice help me a lot. Please don't be mad at me if I'm asking so basic questions. Thank you again guys.